# Check if condition and then update Magento

Tags: php, magento

need to update price list in magento if a condition is true, if it is false skip.

The issue is that don't know why the function _checkIfSkuInStock is returning 1 for all.

I set one product to be in stock and one to be out of stock.

Below is the code that is updating the price list if the sku exist, and i want to add also the the condition if product is in stock, else skip.

```
function _getConnection($type = 'core_read'){
    return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection($type);
}

function _getTableName($tableName){
    return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName($tableName);
}

function _getAttributeId($attribute_code = 'special_price'){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql = "SELECT attribute_id
                FROM " . _getTableName('eav_attribute') . "
            WHERE
                entity_type_id = ?
                AND attribute_code = ?";
    $entity_type_id = _getEntityTypeId();
    return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_id, $attribute_code));
}

function _getEntityTypeId($entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "SELECT entity_type_id FROM " . _getTableName('eav_entity_type') . " WHERE entity_type_code = ?";
    return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_code));
}

function _getIdFromSku($sku){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "SELECT entity_id FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . " WHERE sku = ?";
    return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));

}

function _checkIfSkuExists($sku){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_no FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . " WHERE sku = ?";
    $count      = $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));
    if($count > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function _checkIfSkuInStock($sku){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_no FROM " . _getTableName('cataloginventory_stock_item') . " WHERE is_in_stock = 1";
    $count      = $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));
    if($count > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function _updatePrices($data){
    $connection     = _getConnection('core_write');
    $sku            = $data[0];
    $newspecial_price       = $data[1];
    $productId      = _getIdFromSku($sku);
    $attributeId    = _getAttributeId();

    $sql = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_decimal') . " cped
                SET  cped.value = ?


               WHERE  cped.attribute_id = ?
                AND cped.entity_id = ?";
        $connection->query($sql, array($newspecial_price, $attributeId, $productId));
    }

$csv                = new Varien_File_Csv();
$data               = $csv->getData('special_price.csv'); //path to csv
array_shift($data);    

    $message = '';
$count   = 1;
foreach($data as $_data){
    if(_checkIfSkuExists($_data[0]) and _checkIfSkuInStock($_data[0]) == 0){
        try{
            _updatePrices($_data);
            $message .= $count . '> Success:: (' . $_data[1] . ') product code  (' . $_data[0] . '). <br />';

        }catch(Exception $e){
            $message .=  $count .'> Error:: While Upating  Price (' . $_data[1] . ') of Sku (' . $_data[0] . ') => '.$e->getMessage().'<br />';
        }
    }else{
        $message .=  $count .'> Error:: Product code   (' . $_data[0] . ')  not in database<br />';
    }
    $count++;
}
echo $message;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code :

```
function _checkIfSkuInStock($sku){
$connection = _getConnection('core_read');
$sql        = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_no FROM " . _getTableName('cataloginventory_stock_item') . " WHERE is_in_stock = 1";
$count      = $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));
if($count > 0){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

}

You try to populate with sku : $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku)); 
But you don't have any prepared field (?) in your request.

Add something like this :

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_no FROM " . _getTableName('cataloginventory_stock_item') . " WHERE is_in_stock = 1 AND product_id=?"
```

And then use

```
$connection->fetchOne($sql, array($this->_getIdFromSku($sku)));
```

It should work better ;)

Comment: Hi @dagfr and thanks for this solution, is here a small issue but cannot understand why. == Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in: $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($this->_getIdFromSku($sku)));

Comment: Check if in the previous line there's no missing ';' after the SQL request (I copy/paste it without the ';')

Comment: Sorry, found semicolon missing, but now i get this error: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($this->_getIdFromSku($sku)));

Comment: my bad, you're not in an object context, use directly _getIdFromSku($sku) (I'm too OOP oriented)

Comment: Yes, i see that, im not a very advanced in php.. So yes, now is perfect working, i changed the is_in_stock to manage_stock because this need to modify the price only on manage_stock to 1, Thanks allot